# Selecting First value when between to dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table below: I need to capture the first service date when that date is between StartDate and EndDate, below is my syntax.

TableA

```
ServiceDate    StartDate    EndDate    ID   PROGRAM
  11/25/15       12/14/15   12/17/15    1    HIGH   
  12/14/15       12/14/15   12/17/15    1    HIGH
  1/20/16        12/14/15   12/14/15    1    HIGH
```

Output:

```
       StartDate    EndDate    ID   PROGRAM  FIRST_SERVICE_DT
         12/14/15   12/17/15    1    HIGH      12/14/15
```

sql

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN SERVICEDATE NOT BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE THEN NULL
  WHEN SERVICEDATE BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE THEN FIRST_VALUE(TRUNC(SERVICEDATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SERVICEDATE)
  ID ORDER BY SERVICEDATE)
  END FIRST_SERVICE_DT
```

My query is producing incorrect results, what needs to happen to get my desired output?

Comment: You only need records whose servicedate is between startdate and enddate and discard remaining records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `min` window function.

```
select * 
from (select t.*
      ,min(case when service_date between start_date and end_date then service_date end) over(partition by id) as first_service_date
      from tbl t
     ) t
where service_date=first_service_date
```

Comment: This syntax throws and error.  min(case when service_date between start_date and end_date then service_date) over(partition by id) as first_service_date

Comment: aah..i missed to `end` the `case` expression.edited it.should work now.

Comment: Got it, add the `End` clause after the `Then`